# como usar Order by em ENUM

Tags: php, mysqli

Ola gostaria de saber como usar o `ORDER BY` para fazer o seguinte na minha SQL tabela categoria coluna modulo eu tenho um `ENUM` com os seguintes modos `'media','filme','ova'` gostaria de fazer uma aplicação para ordenar da seguinte forma no código abaixo para ordenar os itens na ordem `media, ova e filme` isso no `ORDER BY am2.modulo` e possível ?

```
    $medias_skin = $MySQLiconn->query("
    SELECT `am1`.id,`am1`.cat,`am1`.subcat,`am1`.numero,`am1`.episodioTipo,`am1`.fillerType,`am1`.duploType,`am1`.finalType, `am1`.autor,`am1`.fansub,`am1`.arquivo_nome,`am1`.url,`am1`.url2,`am1`.url3,`am1`.url4,`am1`.url5,`am1`.url6,`am1`.url7,`am1`.url8,`am1`.url13,`am1`.url14,`am1`.url15,`am1`.url16,`am1`.url17,`am1`.url18,`am1`.url19,`am1`.url20,`am1`.url25,`am1`.url26,`am1`.url27,`am1`.url28,`am1`.url29,`am1`.url30,`am1`.url31,`am1`.url32,`am1`.linknome01,`am1`.linknome02,`am1`.linknome03,`am1`.linknome04,`am1`.linknome05,`am1`.linknome06,`am1`.linknome07,`am1`.linknome08,`am1`.linknome13,`am1`.linknome14,`am1`.linknome15,`am1`.linknome16,`am1`.linknome17,`am1`.linknome18,`am1`.linknome19,`am1`.linknome20,`am1`.linknome25,`am1`.linknome26,`am1`.linknome27,`am1`.linknome28,`am1`.linknome29,`am1`.linknome30,`am1`.linknome31,`am1`.linknome32, `am1`.player,`am3`.`nome` as mediaNome, `am3`.`animes_categoria_url` as catUrl, `am3`.`animes_subcategoria_url` as subcatUrl, `am2`.`modo` as categoriaModo, `am2`.`modulo` as categoriaModulo, `am2`.`nome` as catNome 
    FROM `m_medias` as am1 USE INDEX (medias_indexadas)
    INNER JOIN `m_categoria` as am2 USE INDEX (categoria_index) ON `am1`.`cat` = `am2`.`id` 
    INNER JOIN `m_subcategoria` as am3 USE INDEX (subcategoria_index) ON `am1`.`subcat` = `am3`.`id` AND `am1`.`cat` = `am3`.`cat`
    WHERE am1.id IN ($media_id)
    GROUP BY `am1`.`id`,`am1`.`subcat`
    ORDER BY am2.modulo 
    ");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado no exemplo da [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html#enum-sorting):

> Valores [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html) são classificados com base em seus números de índice, que dependem da ordem em que os membros de enumeração foram listados na especificação da coluna. Por exemplo, os tipos "B" antes "a" para ENUM ('b', 'a'). Os tipos cadeia vazia antes strings não-vazias, e valores NULL vem antes de todos os outros valores de enumeração.
>
> Para evitar resultados inesperados ao usar a cláusula ORDER BY em uma coluna ENUM, use um dos seguintes técnicas:
>
> - Especifique a lista ENUM em ordem alfabética.
> - Certifique-se de que a coluna é classificadas em ordem alfabética e não por número de índice de codificação ORDER BY CAST (col AS CHAR) ou ORDER BY CONCAT (col).

Para uma consulta usando o [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html), seria então:

```
SELECT enum_col FROM tbl_name ORDER BY CAST(enum_col AS CHAR);
```

Para o teu caso:

```
ORDER BY CAST(am2.modulo AS CHAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Para dados numéricos**, considerando que media é 1, ova é 2 e filme é 3:

1. am2.modulo -> 1 (media)
2. am2.modulo -> 2 (mova)
3. am2.modulo -> 3 (filme)

   ORDER BY am2.modulo ASC

**Para dados em formato char ou varchar**, deverá criar uma tabela para indicar a ordem.

Exemplo

Tabela `modulo_position`

Colunas:

```
modulo_id
modulo_position
```

Por fim, tudo depende da modelagem.

Recomendo que utilize a segunda abordagem, criando uma tabela onde terá as referências de ordenação.